# How to create a Remote Desktop Server on Ubuntu Server per user

Tags: command-line, gdm, users, remote

I want to create an old style server - thinclient/terminal kind of work with ubuntu server 12.04. I was trying to use x11vnc to serve remote desktops to users but from what I have understood [after couple of hours] it directly serves the x display of/to only one user. I want to have something like windows 2008 RDS-login where every user connects and logins to his own desktop and has his own working environment.

Is it possible with ubuntu server ?

Thank you

Edit: It seems that xrdp is able to serve such service. I will check it out.

Edit2: XRDP does really create the environment I want and works fast and good. I only had a small problem with default xsessions for each login. The solution was to create a .xsession file in ~ of user and add 
    gnome-session --session=gnome
Now I am trying to change session language for xrdp. Altough user accounts changed their language settings, xrdp session always comes up with default english.

Edit3:I changed /etc/default/locale to my desired language changing whole operating system to my native language still looking for a way to configure it for per user

Comment: If you've managed to answer your question yourself then it's good practice to post it as an answer. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for informational purposes I will answer my own question and tell about what happened.

After the mentioned changes in question XRDP worked but there are problems with XRDP that can not be easily solved. For example there is no way to work with Xrdp on a non-english keyboard. From my searches I couldn't find a solution nor a work around for this problem which is fatal as every keyboard in our company was Turkish.[I later found solution as creating XRDP keyboard map files. But we failed to this as setxkbmap also did not work for various reasons. [Check here](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=265100)]

So we dropped Xrdp for the favor of NX. NX is a library written by NoMachine it is GPL also has some enterprise verisons. There is also FreeNX implementation but support seemed to be vanished.

Anyway installation of NoMachine NX is easy and straight forward although you have to do the same trick with .xsession file in home directory of the user to set default desktop if you did not installed unity but only gnome.

As NoMachine NX has also enterprise edition I will not talk about the results we get from it in sake of avoiding advertisement.

As a last thing it just takes a little bit longer and more tiresome to achive the same results with XRDP altough at the end when they both work NX is faster and gives you more easier configuration they can both achieve same terminal-desktop per user result quite satisfactorily.